# How to set up off session payments with Stripe and 3D secure?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a website similar to TaskRabbit (employers hire employees). I'm trying to figure out how to set up payments to work with 3D secure - even though I'm in the United States and I don't think that many cards require it.

The payment flow is

- Employers go to the Stripe hosted Customer portal to enter their payment method, and if they need authentication when entering a 3D secure card, Stripe will handle that there
- Employers will bid on shifts for Employees. Since multiple bids may be needed and not all bids would be accepted by the employee, I don't have any payment processing done at this stage
- Employee accepts a bid. Now using the stored payment method, an off session Payment Intent is created. PaymentIntent looks like this

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents
  -d amount=1000 
  -d currency=usd
  -d customer = cus_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP 
  -d automatic_payment_methods[enabled] = true
  -d payment_method = pm_1MYlwuGbdc
  -d confirm = true
  -d transfer_data[destination] = acct_1MVqZx2eFvmfdu
  -d off_session = true
  -d transfer_data[amount] = 100
```

And this works for a few test cards in Stripe but not for this one for example:

```
This card requires authentication on all transactions, regardless of how the card is set up.
```

Right now my website is not live. How likely am I to encounter problems in the US with 3D secure? Is my payment flow going to be possible (the main thing is I don't want the employer having to go through a Checkout process)

Answer (score 0):

When you collect payment method details at first, you should use the Setup Intents [API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents) to properly set up the payment method for future use. For card payments for example you will be able to have your customer go through 3D Secure if it's required.

After the SetupIntent succeeds, you will get a PaymentMethod `pm_123` attached to your customer which you can use on future payments either on or off session.

Now, even if the card is set up properly, it's still possible that the bank will decline the payment. It might be because they want the cardholder to go through 3D Secure again, but it might simply be that they have insufficient funds or any other reason.

When that happens, your code should handle the payment failure and get your customer back on session to enter new payment method details. It might be a new card, or the existing one but they go through 3D Secure again. And that payment can still fail, the same as any payment.

Finally, the test card you are using was explicitly built by Stripe to always require 3DS. It's not really something most banks would do, it's just an easy card to use for forcing any transaction to require 3DS in Test mode. But ultimately, it'd work the same as any decline: you get the customer back "on session" on your website/app and you confirm that PaymentIntent client-side instead.